# Shared library implementing abstract class in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries

I have an executable C++ project **prj** which should be capable of using any shared library that implements its interface, provided as an abstract class **inter.h**.

I am not sure about where inter.h should be:

- If inter.h is defined in prj, the libraries (e.g lib1.cpp) would need to refer to prj in order to have access to inter.h.
- A second option is to put inter.h as an external project to which prj and lib1 make references.

The questions are:

- Is any of these good options, or there is an alternative way of doing
  the job.
- In Eclipse, should I add the project containing inter.h as Includes
  or References?
- Which path do I have to put in the `#include` of lib1.cpp to make
  reference to inter.h?